# Reporting Services 2012 "Page 0 of 0"

Tags: asp.net, sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reporting-services-2012

Created a report using 2012 Report Builder and it works fine within the 2010 Visual Studio IDE. After deploying to a server, however, the report will intermittently display "0 of 0" in the page navigation tool on the toolbar when viewed in a browser. The functionality of the navigation elements is disabled.

Couldn't find much information, but did discover this older (2011) blog article on MSDN:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2011/04/28/browsing-a-report-from-report-manager-report-server-always-show-page-0-of-0-in-the-tool-bar.aspx

... which referenced another blog article as the solution (even though it references a sorting issue in Reporting Services):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2011/04/28/interactive-sorting-in-reporting-service-fails-with-rsreportnotready-exception.aspx

Now I believe this addresses the heart of our problem, because we've recently revised our SQL isolation level settings on our servers to improve performance. Our concern of course is that if we do adjust these settings as per the blog article, we'll lose the performance benefit we need.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: The article only suggests turning off read committed snapshot for the report server databases, not your user databases, so performance of your queries should not be impacted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That sounds right to me; I'll give this question a little time but it looks like you'll probably get an up vote.

Comment: I should probably move my comment into the answer section then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article only suggests turning off read committed snapshot for the report server databases, not your user databases, so performance of your queries should not be impacted.

Comment: Thanks again, @steoleary... unfortunately I haven't earned enough reputation points to give you an up-vote.